# Describe the smallest topology for $X$ which makes $f$ continuous.

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $X$ be any set and let $(Y,\mathcal{T}^\ast)$ be a topological space. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Describe the smallest topology for $X$ which makes $f$ continuous.

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this? I can not find a way to solve this. Any guidance or help will be useful.

Comment: What's the deifnition of CONTINUITY? Assume you know what $T^*$ is.... How MUST you define $T$ to be continuous?

Comment: I know the definition of continuity. The problem is $T^*$ isn't precisely known. This is creating the problem. I can not simple assume $T^*$ to be any topology, such information is not given in the problem.

Comment: Which subsets of $X$ have to be open if $f$ is going to be continuous? Do those sets comprise a topology?

Comment: How many sets should there be in topology $T$ on $X$, the problem is I don't know no. of sets in $T^*$ topology. The map $f^-1(V)$ has to be open in $X$ for each $V$ in $Y$. I don't know how many subsets of $X$,  I must take to make smallest topology, and also so that no $V$ is left in $Y$ to map.